# Parts of site disappear on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the [site](http://badboybranding.com/).

For some reason, the site is showing messed up at resolutions: `1440x900, 1366x768, 1280x800, 1280x768 and 1152x864`.

Just need a little bit of help here. This was unexpected.

Any insight would be more than grateful.

Answer (score 0):

That's done with CSS3 Media Queries.

This webpage makes it clear:

[CSS3 Media Queries explained](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)

Comment: Ok thank you, I looked at the site.  the words on the home page and the log are getting cut off.  This happens on laptops 13"-15".  I am looking for a solution.  Is the media query what I need in this instance?  Can you look at the css by inspecting the site?

Comment: The CSS in these media queries is not right, but this website is not made to get people to fix your website, you should consider hiring a front-end web developer for this, lol.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I was looking for insight so I can learn.  I know its easy to hire someone, but then I won't learn.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer.  It was in the html and not the css all along.

Thank you for the help though.

```
  <section id="slider">
     <div class="tp-banner-container">
        <div class="tp-banner" >
           <ul>
              <!-- SLIDE NR. 1-->
              <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="5" data-masterspeed="0">
                 <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                 <img src="img/slider/fullscreen/1.jpg"  alt="Badboy Branding" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                 <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->   
                 <div class="tp-caption mediumlarge_light_white_center customin customout start"
                    data-x="center"                             
                    data-y="15" <----------THIS WAS WHERE THE FIX IS------------***                         
                    data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:90;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:1;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:200;transformOrigin:50% 0%;"
                    data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;"
                    data-speed="1000"
                    data-start="1000"
                    data-easing="Back.easeInOut"
                    data-endspeed="300"><img src="img/logo/logo-big.png" alt="Badboy Branding">
                 </div>
```